# Tensorflow Android: '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:cc_configure.bzl' does not contain symbol 'cc_autoconf_impl'

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am testing Tensorflow Android example in Android Studio. After git clone the repository, I only edit the bazel path and WORKSPACE file to set the SDK and NDK path. When I tried to run the application, it shows the error.

> Error:/home/sam/FYP/tensorflow/third_party/clang_toolchain/cc_configure_clang.bzl:3:1: file '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:cc_configure.bzl' does not contain symbol 'cc_autoconf_impl'
>
> Error:error loading package '': Extension file 'third_party/clang_toolchain/cc_configure_clang.bzl' has errors
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':buildNativeBazel'.
> Process 'command '/usr/bin/bazel'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My environment setup should not be the problem as I have successfully run the Android example for the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

About two month ago I successfully built Tensorflow but with recent master branch I faced same problem.

For me, upgrading bazel(0.9.0 to 0.11.1) resolved it. My environment is macOS with `brew upgrade bazel`.